# ASP.NET Boilerplate - Background Worker

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need to know where is the best place to implement the background worker.
Web.Core or Core modules.

I am considering hosting my host project and MVC project on different VM's and do not want the background worker to run twice ie on both VMS.

Thanks

Comment: One option is you can implement hangfire using, Abp.Hangfire, and based on some configuration, don't enable app.UseHangfireServer();... on the server you don't want

Comment: Is it possible just to add the background worker to the MVC project

Comment: If both host and mvc project is hosted on the same server would it only run once then.

Comment: yes by the method i told you hangfire would work on one server.
and if you want abp background worker, you can try this setting on a configuration basis https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Background-Jobs-And-Workers#disabling-job-execution